# Unable to scrape data with beautiful soup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the code I want to scrape

```
<li id="shortlink">
<strong>Short link:</strong>
<input id="short-link-input" type="text" value="http://tnydu.biz/DfBCAEk" onclick="dbzglobal_event_adapter();">
</li>
```

The script i am using is this:

```
 shortlink=soup.select("#short-link-input value")
    
            print shortlink
```

but it gives [] output and I cannot extract the link for it. Available methods are find and select. can someone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
elem = soup.find('input',{'id':'short-link-input'})
print elem.get('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shortlink=soup.select("#short-link-input")[0]['value']
```

`select`-method returns a list of elements. To get the value of an attribute, you have to call its `get`-method or use the attribute's name as key-index